# By using the CLI on Linux, can I make a running blender instance save its current scene to file?

Tags: blend-files, command-line, linux

I have a desktop machine that has been baking a physics (rigid body) simulation. I am now from another computer, and I have `ssh` access to the remote one. In the remote `/tmp` folder the last autosave is from before "bake" was invoked.

Is there a way to send a signal in order to make the existing blender instance save its current scene to file, or to trigger its autosave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Blender accepts cli options when starting that can include a python script to automate tasks but once started it no longer accepts commands from the cli.

The autosave, if is hasn't been disabled, should save a temporary copy, even the unmodified startup file will regularly autosave a temporary copy. If your autosave file is old then it may indicate that the copy of blender is no longer running.

If you can't get back to the machine (or get someone else) to close it properly then the only option I can think of trying is [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) that can connect to an existing xorg desktop. See if you can download a copy to your home folder and run it without admin permissions.

Comment: If you want to connect to a Linux desktop from outside, use x2go, it is the most functional project for it, install x2goserver on the machine you want to connect to, and x2goclient on the source machine, which can be Linux, Windows or Mac and it will allow you to open a desktop even over a slow link, via ssh and it uses existing users. It allows also sound, printer and file sharing and session resume.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it via ssh, but there is a simple method: using https://www.teamviewer.com It's cross-platform, gui-based, and easy to use. And you can access to blender gui from over OS and even from smartphone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this would require having prepared the remote machine before (by installing teamviewer on it). Also, I'm not sure I could install it since I am not root on the remote machine